# Adding tables in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

If I have a table that looks like `table1 = {x = 0, y = 0}` and another table that looks like `table2 = {x = 0, y = 2}` I want to be able to add them like this

```
table1 += table2 --table1 now == {x = 0, y = 2}
```

the equivalent c++ code would look like:

```
typedef struct {int x; int y;} S;
S s1 = {0, 0};
S s2 = {0, 2};
int add(S ls1, S ls2)
{
    s1.x = s1.x + s2.x;
    s1.y = s1.y + s2.y;
    return s1.x;
}

int main() {
    add(s1, s2);
    std::cout << s1.x << " " << s1.y;
}
```

or even better

```
#include <iostream>



typedef struct {int x; int y;} S;
S s1 = {0, 0};
S s2 = {0, 2};
int operator+=(S ls1, S ls2)
{
    s1.x = s1.x + s2.x;
    s1.y = s1.y + s2.y;
    return s1.x;
}

int main() {
    s1 += s2;
    std::cout << s1.x << " " << s1.y;
}
```

Comment: Your pointless use of `typedef struct` in C++ is shameful. Also, why is your `add` function only returning one of the values instead of `S`? Equally importantly, why does your `operator+=` not return an `S&` like it's supposed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

Simply implement a add function like warspyking suggested.

or

Implement the same function and set it as the tables' __add metamethod similar to what Digital Veer suggested. Although I would define an object here for convenience and only add the 2 components x and y as you wished. Otherwise you would have to set the metatable for both tables manually every time.

```
Point = {}

function Point:New(x,y)

  local o = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  self.__add = function (p1,p2) return Point:New(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y) end
  o.x = type(x) == "number" and x or 0
  o.y = type(y) == "number" and y or 0

  return o

end
```

Then you can do something like:

```
local a = Point:New(1,1)
local b = Point:New(2,2)
local c = a + b
```

Comment: I'd be interested in why this was down-voted. Please comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate...

```
function add(t1,t2)
    local new = {}
    for i,v in pairs(t1) do
        if type(v) == "number" and type(t2[i]) == "number" then
            new[i] = v + t2[i]
        else
            new[i] = v
        end
    end
    return new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that both tables have the same index keys, then you can simply use the `_add` metamethod to allow for this:

```
local table1 = {x=0, y=2, z=3}
local table2 = {x=0,y=5}

local meta = {
    __add = function(t1, t2)
        local new = {}
        for i,v in pairs(t1) do
           if t2[i] then
             new[i] = t1[i] + t2[i]
           end
        end
   return new
end
}

setmetatable(table1,meta)
setmetatable(table2,meta)

for k, v in pairs(table1 + table2) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Comment: if you exchange table1 and table2 it won't work properly as the result won't have a third element. you don't check if t1 and t2 are tables. you don't check if their elements are numbers.
setting a metatable every time you want to add is also pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Lua doesn't have a formal class system. You can share code through the metatable system, which includes `__index`, `__tostring` and `__add`.

You asked for an operator `+=`. Lua has a fixed set of operators. Although, you can define them for your tables, you can't create new ones. So, `+=` is out. As, @Piglet [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36233747/2226988), you can define `+` using the `_add` metamethod. Of course, `+` doesn't modify the left operand. While that might be better, it is not what you modeled.

A method more like you modeled (but I'll call the method "offset" and the parameter "delta") is like this:

```
local S = {}
S.__index = S -- expose members of S to tables created by S:New

function S:New(x,y)
  return setmetatable({ x=x, y=y }, self)
end

function S:__tostring()
    return tostring(self.x) .. " " .. tostring(self.y)
end

function S:Offset(delta)
   self.x = self.x + delta.x
   self.y = self.y + delta.y
   return self
end

-- Example…

local s1 = S:New(0,0)
local s2 = S:New(1,2)
print(s1:Offset(s2))
print(s1)
```